# How to convert MAC string to colon-separated string

Tags: java, string-conversion

I have csv file with 200k rows and 3 types of MAC address defined as:

- ECE1A9312000
- E8:6D:52:75:2D:16
- 24-C9-A1-15-89-B0

My goal to stay only with colon-separated form.

So to convert `-` to `:` is not big deal:

```
mac = mac.replace("-", ":");
```

But how to convert `ECE1A9312000` to `EC:E1:A9:31:20:00`.

I thought to use regex but its too expensive to use groups for so many data (~80k).

Do I need to run over each `char` and append `:`

like:

```
for(int i=0; i<mac.length(); i++){
    ch = mac.charAt(i);

    if(i % 2 == 0 && i != 0){
        tmp += ':';
    }
    tmp += ch;
}
```

or there is more efficient way?

Thank you,

Comment: 80k is very little data. You should post your regex code and specific timing results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I threw together a totally unoptimized program based on your discarded regex approach and timed it. It completed in 650 ms (250 ms with warmup). The slowest part doesn't involve the regex, but `String.format`. If we replace it with a straight `StringBuilder` approach, the time drops to 40 ms.

```
public class Test {
  static Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)");
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> inMacs = new ArrayList<>(), outMacs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 80_000; i++) inMacs.add(mac());
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (String mac : inMacs) {
      final Matcher m = regex.matcher(mac);
      m.matches();
      outMacs.add(String.format("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s",
          m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5), m.group(6)));
    }
    System.out.println("Took " + (System.nanoTime() - start)/1_000_000 + " milliseconds");
    final Iterator<String> it = outMacs.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) System.out.println(it.next());
  }

  static Random rnd = new Random();
  static String mac() {
    final long mac = (long) (rnd.nextDouble()*(1L<<48));
    return String.format("%012x", mac).toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

If you are really looking for a fast solution, then avoid the regex and use a simple test to detect your MAC format:

```
  static List<String> fixMacs(List<String> inMacs) {
    final List<String> outMacs = new ArrayList<>(inMacs.size());
    for (String mac : inMacs) outMacs.add(
          mac.charAt(2) == '-'? mac.replace("-", ":")
        : mac.charAt(2) != ':'? fixMac(mac)
        : mac);
    return outMacs;
  }

  static String fixMac(String inMac) {
    final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(18);
    for (int i = 0; i < inMac.length(); i++) {
      b.append(inMac.charAt(i));
      if (i%2 == 1 && i != inMac.length()-1) b.append(':');
    }
    return b.toString();
  }
```

With this approach I measured just 8 ms for your 80,000 MACs.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through it character by character, every two steps if the character found is '-' replace it with ':', if it's a letter or a number then insert a ':' character.

Comment: it's not what I asked, I need `ECE1A9312000 -> EC:E1:A9:31:20:00`

Comment: @fessy check my answer and let me know if you want this way or not

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String x="ECE1A9312000";
String finals="";
for(int i=0;i<x.length();i=i+2)
{
    if((i+2)<x.length())
finals+=x.substring(i, i+2)+":";
    if((i+2)==x.length())
    {
        finals+=x.substring(i, i+2);

    }

}
System.out.println(finals);
```

**output**
EC:E1:A9:31:20:00

Comment: Do you think its faster way against I posted above? `substring`, hmm

Comment: @fessy in your way for loop will run for 12 times because you are doing i++ but I am doing i=2 but this will not matter.But instead of reading character by character why not just substring it and also let me know if you have any other query.

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Split every 2 chars with regexp and join with delimiter using `String.join`:

```
public static String convertToColonSeparatedMac(String mac) {

    if (mac.contains(":"))
        return mac;

    if (mac.contains("-")) 
        return mac.replaceAll("-", ":");

    return String.join(":", mac.split("(?<=\\G.{2})"));
}
```

And you may validate it before converting:

```
private static final Pattern MAC_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$)|([0-9A-Fa-f]{12})");

public static boolean isValidMac(String mac) {
    return MAC_PATTERN.matcher(mac).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String mac[] = {"ECE1A9312000", "24-C9-A1-15-89-B0", "E8:6D:52:75:2D:16"};

    for (int i = 0; i< mac.length; i++)
    {
        if (mac[i].charAt(2) == '-')
            mac[i] = mac[i].replace("-", ":");
        else if (mac[i].charAt(2) != ':')
            mac[i] = new StringBuilder(mac[i].substring(0,2)).append(":").append(mac[i].substring(2,4))
                    .append(":").append(mac[i].substring(4,6)).append(":").append(mac[i].substring(6,8))
                    .append(":").append(mac[i].substring(8,10)).append(":").append(mac[i].substring(10)).toString();        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< mac.length; i++)
        System.out.println(mac[i]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
EC:E1:A9:31:20:00
24:C9:A1:15:89:B0
E8:6D:52:75:2D:16
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes! Thank you! I've removed it.

Comment: I've timed this and it's just as fast (or slow :) as my approach with regex. I don't think OP's complaint about performance stands.

Comment: BTW since the input is constrained to just three formats, the most efficient way to detect the format is to just check `mac[2]`.

Comment: I've now written code which avoids `String.format` and it turns out that this call is the real drag: my time dropped from 250 ms to just 10 ms.

Comment: I've noted a factor of 10 improvement by using `StringBuilder` instead of format. I've also seen that `StringBuilder` is a bit faster than @MarkoTopolnik 's `fixMac` (at least, in my laptop).

Comment: But my `fixMac` also has `StringBuilder`. Do you mean the difference between the ways we use it? Because I wanted to avoid `substring` as well. It would be a very interesting finding if it turns out that `substring` is faster than my approach.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Forget it, my mistake. I've run a few more tests, and in fact, your `fixMac` runs a lot faster than my `StringBuilder` naive approach.